# How to solve UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: Operation `menus.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms this problem in node js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Above these pic code is given
How to solve this problem.
When I use this code the error will show

```
const Menu = require('../../models/menu')
function homeController() {
    return {
        async index(req, res) {
            const pizzas = await Menu.find()
            return res.render('home', { pizzas: pizzas })
        }
    }
}

module.exports = homeController
```

Comment: Is your mongodb local or on some cloud service like atlas?

Comment: Yes i use atlas.